# extract long/lat from a string

Tags: php, regex

HI,

I have a string that could contain a longitude and a latitude. The string could contain anything but if it does contain a lon/lat then I want to extract it using php. I think I need a regular expression but I don't have a clue how to get that out. The string could contain anything:

a random string dfdff33338983 33.707352,-116.272797 more dfdfndfdf

Comment: do we assume there's no fixed location within the string to for both longitude and latitude? and can they be in reverse order? give us more details.

Comment: no unfortunately the long/lat could be anywhere in the string. they could appear to be in reverse order as sometimes a long or lat has a minus in front of it and others it doesn't

Comment: then you're waiting for trouble to happen. longitude values range from -180 to 180. latitude ranges from -90 to 90. how do u propose to interpret something like -38.02342,48.09812? how do u know which is longitude and latitude then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match using this:

```
.*\s(.*),(.*?)\s.*
```

See this answer in [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/UAZA11viLl).

Answer in php:

```
$txt = "dfdff333 38983 33.707352,-116.272797 dfd fndfdf";
$lat = preg_replace("/.*\s(.*),.*?\s.*/", "$1", $txt);
$lon = preg_replace("/.*\s.*,(.*?)\s.*/", "$1", $txt);

echo $lat."\n"; // 33.707352
echo $lon."\n"; // -116.272797
```

Note: I'm using comma as delimiter.

---

EDIT: you can use a more specif regex, like

```
$lat = preg_replace("/.*\s(-?\d+\.\d+),-?\d+\.\d+?\s.*/", "$1", $txt);
$lon = preg_replace("/.*\s-?\d+\.\d+,(-?\d+\.\d+?)\s.*/", "$1", $txt);
```

Tks @soapbox.

Comment: that seems to work really well....but I really need to do it in. would that regex work in PHP?

Comment: Check the answer now. I changed to php answer. :)

Comment: I disapprove of using .* to match the numbers.  You should be using `-?\d+\.\d+` because they have a well defined format.  using .* here will match all kinds of other unexpected things.

Answer (score 4):

If the string could contain *anything*, then there is *no* regular expression, or indeed any piece of code that could extract the longitude and latitude.

This can be confirmed with the following string:

```
7.123456,40.404040 is nothing like 33.707352,-116.272797 or 99.111222,-22.333444.
```

Which one of those is the latitude?

You could try something like:

```
\b-?\d+\.\d{6},-?\d+\.\d{6}\b
```

as a starting point.

Comment: Oh ok. I was thinking something like...if there's an integer in the string and if that number has a dot either 2 or 3 characters along from that then I could pretty much be fairly sure it was a longitude...from there just take the whole string up to the next comma. That would give you the longitude...then look for the minus and a character and take that string up to the next space and that would give you the lat. It doesn't need to be perfect...just be good if i could get it most of the time.

Is this no do-able?

Comment: actually that wouldn't work because sometimes long lat can start with a minus sign and others they don't

Comment: @elduderino, that's a lot different than "string could contain anything" :-) Have a look at the regex I provided as a starting point. You can use `?` to indicate zero or one occurrences.

Comment: Note that there is no reason why a lat/lon combination must include decimal points. 60,10 is a perfectly valid coordinate. Decimal points may even be swapped for commas if your input is depending on a locale.